# Is it possible to create a named entity recognition system without using POS tagging in the corpus?

Tags: natural-language-processing, named-entity-recognition, pos-tagging

Is it possible to create a named entity recognition system without using POS tagging in the corpus?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both of them are different tasks. POS tagging helps NER systems but it is not necessary. You can get features (say BERT/ELMo embedding) for each word in the sentence and train a CRF NER model. This looks like simple example https://www.pragnakalp.com/bert-named-entity-recognition-ner-tutorial-demo/